# How can I edit this so it works with files that have spaces?

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
@echo off
set /A Counter=0
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%D in ("e:\test test\") do (
    for /f %%F in ('dir /a-d /b %%D*.*') do (
            ECHO.
        ECHO Current file is: %%F 
        set src=%%F
            set dest="e:\test test\space locate\%%F"
        if not exist !dest! move !src! !dest! 

        if exist !dest! (
            ECHO.
            ECHO ERROR: "%%F" already exists
            set /A Counter+=1
        )

        ECHO source file is !src!
        ECHO destination is !dest!

    )
)
echo.
echo %Counter% files not moved.
```

Comment: you won't get much help without making the effort to properly explain your problem. a dump of the code and "it doesn't work" isn't what SO is meant for.

Comment: @pstanton: The title does give the problem statement: Files that have spaces in them do not get moved.

Comment: @pstanton sorry I have never used this site before so I didn't quite get how to properly format the code.

Answer (score 1):

You probably just need to put quotes (`"`) around all your filenames.

I'm talking about this sort of thing:

```
if not exist "!dest!" move "!src!" "!dest!"
```

That's just a suggestion, I don't have time to actually try to debug it right now.

Edit in response to comment:

`for` by default uses spaces as delimiters. You should say `for /f "delims="` instead of just `for /f` in order to tell it not to do that.

Comment: `dest` has quotes already ... you only need to put them around `src` here. Still, +1 as it should be the solution.

Comment: When I tried that it still isn't taking in files that have a space in them :(
http://pastebin.com/m1e766aa2